# Joomla 2.5 frontend pagination clicking on next button not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using joomala 2.5 and developed my own component for showing table data in front end and added pagination. I'm getting pagination links, after clicking on the links 'next', 'prev' nothing happens. 
What may be the problem?
In view.html.php I've added

```
$this -> pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

In default.php I've added

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what you have done in you components model file. My advoice to you is just read this document carefully http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_JPagination_in_your_component & you will be easily apply pagination. The doc is perfect & its very simple to use pagination in Joomla.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your pagination buttons inside a  tag and make sure the action url points to the same view (e.g. action = 'index.php?option=com_component&view=listview')

```
<form action=""...>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem was database query limit set to 0,20 when I click on the pagination.I override the getStart() method of model and it woks.